# How to Spell Check without using third party library in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I want to implement a method in C# class library project which will take a word as an input parameter and return correct spelling or suggestions of the words using .Net `PresentationFramework.dll` dll.

In WPF, PresentationFramework.dll provides this feature for a text box control when we enable the SpellCheck property value to true.

```
<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Name="myTextBox"></TextBox>
```

But I need similar feature in class library project where I will not have any controls to type the input value. Just I want to use this spell check feature in custom method. Is there any way to use this DLL functionality to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

There is the win32 [Spellcheck API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/spellcheck/nf-spellcheck-ispellchecker-check).

```
HRESULT Check(
  [in]          LPCWSTR            text,
  [out, retval] IEnumSpellingError **value
);
```

As far as I know there is no first party wrapper around this in .net, but a quick google suggest there are at least one [third party wrapper](https://github.com/bbowyersmyth/SpellCheck).

So you might need to decide if you want to use a library or write your own wrapper.